# How can I display something from data base after multiple criteria is satisfied in django

Tags: django, django-models

Here i have a Model Recommenders:

```
class Recommenders(models.Model):
    objects = None
    Subject = models.ForeignKey(SendApproval, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Recommender = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    Status = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=8, default="Pending")
    Time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And another model Approvers:

```
class Approvers(models.Model):
    objects = None
    Subject = models.ForeignKey(SendApproval, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Approver = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    Status = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=8, default="Pending")
    Time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And my SendApproval model as:

```
class SendApproval(models.Model):
    Subject = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    Date = models.DateField(null=True)
    Attachment = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path)
    SentBy = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    Status = models.CharField(null= True, max_length=8, default="Pending")
```

Now my problem is that I have to display the Subject and Attachment from SendApproval table only when all the recommender's Status in Recommenders table related to that subject is "Approved"
Don't know how can I know that...Thanks in advance...

Actually not have any Idea about the solution but the best answer will be appreciated...By the way, I am new to StackOverflow...So please let me know if there is some ambiguity in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Offer two ways.

1.Here the Recommenders model is filtered by the Status='Approved' field. By the Subject field, which is associated with the primary model, I get access to the SendApproval fields.

**Replace bboard with the name of the folder where your templates are placed.**
I have this: templates/bboard which are in the application folder.

views.py

```
def info(request):
    recomm = Recommenders.objects.filter(Status='Approved')

    return render(request, 'bboard/templ.html', {'context': recomm})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('info/', info, name='info'),
]
```

templates

```
{% for a in context %}
<p>{{ 'Subject' }} : {{ a.Subject.Subject }} {{ 'Attachment' }} : <a href="{{ a.Subject.Attachment }}">Link</a>
    {{ 'id SendApproval' }} : {{ a.Subject.id }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

2.You can also filter by primary model by fields from a secondary model that is linked to the primary. Here, I passed in the filter the name of the model in lower case and the search field.

In the primary model, by default, a property is created to refer to the secondary model, this is the name of the model in lower case and the _set prefix. In the outer loop, all received rows of the primary model are sorted out, and in the inner loop, through recommenders_set.all(), we get the Status. As you can see it is Approved.

```
sa = SendApproval.objects.filter(recommenders__Status='Approved')
print(sa)
for i in sa:
  for k in i.recommenders_set.all():
     print('status', k.Status)
```